# Dimensions mismatch error when using tf.metrics.MeanIoU() with SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy loss in Tensorflow 2.2

Tags: python, tensorflow

Refer to # https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32875

The suggested fix was to :

```
class UpdatedMeanIoU(tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU):
    @tf.function
    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1) # this is the fix
        return super().__call__(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

It worked for TF2.1, but broke again in TF2.2. Is there a way to pass `y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)` as `y_pred` to this metric other than subclassing ?

Comment: One question,if you argmax the last dimension, why are you using Sparse Categorical Crossentropy instead of Categorical Crossentropy?

Comment: Because my model outputs `num_classes` outputs and my `y_true` is a tensor where each element is an integer representing the class membership.

Comment: And isn't better to categorical your ground target instead of consider the numerical value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This fixes the issue:

```
class UpdatedMeanIoU(tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU):
  def __init__(self,
               y_true=None,
               y_pred=None,
               num_classes=None,
               name=None,
               dtype=None):
    super(UpdatedMeanIoU, self).__init__(num_classes = num_classes,name=name, dtype=dtype)

  def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
```